# Angular 4 - Replace key-value of ArrayList

Tags: json, angular, typescript, arraylist

I have the following [json](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) data, which was read into an [arrayList](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm) and saved in [local-storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Albany",
        "manufacture": "Albany Superior Low Gi Sliced Brown Seed Bread 700g",
        "price": 15.49,
        "category": "Food",
        "type": "Breads",
        "image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA..."
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Blue Ribbon",
        "manufacture": "Blue Ribbon Brown Plus Low Gi Bread 700g",
        "price": 13.99,
        "category": "Food",
        "type": "Breads",
        "image": "data:image/octet-stream;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABA..."
    },
    {...},
    {...},
    ...
]
```

I then wrote a class that will retrieve these data from local-storage, which I filtered for a specific product type. The class is as follows:

```
export class MilkCreamComponent implements OnInit {

  allProducts: Array<Product> = [];
  quantity: number = 1;
  resultArray:any;
  milkProducts =[]
  newMilkProducts = [];

  constructor( private prod: ProductService, public _DomSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.allProducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('product-data') );
    //console.log( JSON.stringify( this.allProducts ) );

    var productMilk = this.allProducts.filter(item => item.type === 'Milk');
    this.milkProducts = productMilk;
    //console.log( this.milkProducts );

      for (var i=0; i < this.milkProducts.length / 4; i++) {
        var imageString = this.milkProducts[i].image;
        var edittedImageString = imageString.substring(imageString.indexOf(",") + 1 );
        var newImageStringFormat = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + edittedImageString;

        if ( edittedImageString ===  this.milkProducts[i].image.substring(this.milkProducts[i].image.indexOf(",") + 1) ){

          var index = this.milkProducts.indexOf( this.milkProducts[i] );

          if (index !== -1) {
            this.milkProducts.indexOf[index] =  this.milkProducts[i].id, this.milkProducts[i].name, this.milkProducts[i].manufacture,
                                this.milkProducts[i].price, this.milkProducts[i].category, this.milkProducts[i].type, newImageStringFormat;
            console.log (  this.milkProducts );
            }
        }
        else{
          console.log("Images Are Not Equal\nSee milk-cream.component.ts\nSee Image Conversion Codes");
        }
      }
    //console.log( this.newMilkProducts );

  }
}

interface Product {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  manufacture: string;
  price: number;
  category: string;
  type: string;
  image: string;
}
```

What I want to do is to replace specific values of a key's, and then console-log that arrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.allProducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('product-data'));

this.allProducts.forEach(function(item) {
  if (item.type === "Milk") {
    var edittedImageString = item.image.substring(item.image.indexOf(",") + 1 );
    item.image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + edittedImageString;
  }
});
```